# Gradle Dependency on Class Binary Directory

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

Is there a way to declare a compile- and runtime dependency for a certain `sourceSet` on a directory that contains binary (`.class`) files? My problem is that I am generating those in one of the build tasks, but I need to have access to them when running / debugging from an IDE.

Currently, my `sourceSets` part of the [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/Dyvil/Dyvil/blob/master/build.gradle) file looks like this:

```
sourceSets {
    library {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/library'
            srcDir 'src/asm'
            srcDir 'src/parsing'

            runtimeClasspath += library.resources
        }
        resources {
            srcDir "${buildDir}/dyvilbin"

            include '**/*.dyo', '**/*.class'
        }
    }

    compiler {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/compiler'
            compileClasspath += library.compileClasspath
            runtimeClasspath += library.runtimeClasspath
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/resources'

            include '**/*.properties'
        }
    }

    repl {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/repl'
            compileClasspath += compiler.compileClasspath
            runtimeClasspath += compiler.runtimeClasspath
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, using `gradle idea`, my IntelliJ project compiles and launches, but during runtime the classes and files from the `build/dyvilbin` and `src/resources` directories cannot be resolved (`ClassNotFoundException`).

Comment: `sourceSets` a *sources*, not compiled classes. You should rather use it as dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution myself, making use of `dependencies`:

```
dependencies {
    // ...

    runtime files("$buildDir/dyvilbin") {
        builtBy 'someCompilerTask'
    }
}
```

To include the output files in the Jar distributions, I added this snippet to the `Jar` tasks:

```
task buildREPL(type: Jar, dependsOn: 'someOtherTask') {
    from sourceSets.repl.output

    from("$buildDir/dyvilbin") {
        include '**/*.dyo', '**/*.class'
    }

    // ...
}
```